# Integeration of sdk and Use of undeclared identifier 'frame'

Tags: ios, xcode, integration

I am trying to integrate an Ad SDK (AdNexus) and I am new to Xcode.

I tried to do the next step:

The banner code sample below shows how to request ads using the placement ID. Beginning with version RC2.8, you can initialize banners using a combination of member ID and inventory code instead (placement ID is still supported). Here are the methods:

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame memberId:(NSInteger)memberId inventoryCode:(NSString *)inventoryCode;
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame memberId:(NSInteger)memberId inventoryCode:(NSString *)inventoryCode adSize:(CGSize)size;
```

- I do not know where to put these lines of code.
- I put them in `viewDidLoad` and they gave me an error "Use of undeclared identifier 'frame'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that those methods return a subclass of `UIView`.

If so, you would want to have a 'container' view in your view controller. Then, you would initialise the ad view with the frame of that container view. The last step is to add the ad view as a subview of the container. You can do this in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Hey Sande,
and Thank you for the response

I don't really know how to do the last step... do you mean do to write 
'-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame memberId:(NSInteger)memberId inventoryCode:(NSString *)inventoryCode;
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame memberId:(NSInteger)memberId inventoryCode:(NSString *)inventoryCode adSize:(CGSize)size;'
inside the containers viewDidLoad function? If so XCode tells me that it is locked for editing... should i enable coding there?

Thanks again!

Comment: No worries! Sorry for not being clear enough. You need to create a container view either using the interface builder or in code. Then you add the ad view as a subview of the container.